# Android: Record raw audio and record video at the same time

Tags: android, audio-recording, video-recording

I develop an Android app based on sound and video records. I would like to get a real-time playback of the mic audio in the headphones while previewing AND capturing the video and sound.

What i have now, working fine alone:

1) use Superpowered library to record audio and playing it back in real-time (during preview and record). Behind the scene, it does directly with C++ the work of AudioRecord by pushing the buffer to the output (headphones). The goal is to apply audio effects on the raw sound in real-time.

2) capture the video with mediaRecorder

When audio playback is running, I try to launch the video record, it crashes starting :

```
E/MediaRecorder: start failed: -2147483648
```

I imagine that i can't launch two recording process at the same time. I think using the AudioRecord or Superpowered lib is the good way to process the raw audio, but I can't figure out how to record video without conflicting with the current audio recording.

So is there a way to achieve my feature?

(minSdk 16)

Comment: I manage to record both at the same time using the MediaRecorder without audioSource for video (and avoid complexity of MediaCodec without MediaMuxer as api16) and my Superpowered lib for the audio. After that I merge my two files using ffmpeg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According [bigflake](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/)

> The MediaCodec class first became available in Android 4.1 (API 16). It was added to allow direct access to the media codecs on the device.
>
> In Android 4.3 (API 18), MediaCodec was expanded to include a way to provide input through a Surface (via the createInputSurface method). This allows input to come from camera preview or OpenGL ES rendering.

So if it's possible please think about increasing MinSDK to 18 and use  [AudioVideoRecordingSample](https://github.com/saki4510t/AudioVideoRecordingSample) or [HWEncoderExperiments](https://github.com/OnlyInAmerica/HWEncoderExperiments) as examples.

Comment: I manage to get the preview of the camera on a surfaceView using MediaCodec, it's a good start. Fo the record I will certainy write in a file at the same time. Normally my audio part can record at the same time.

Comment: There is a latency between audio and video

Comment: Not the best answer but accepted answer : working quite good with mediaCodec and API 18. But I needed to make on API 16. As I said in a previous comment, I disabled audioSource from my recorder, reduce the latency between audio and video making calculations and a good merge with ffmpeg. Cheers guys.